# Failure in adding .pst files to the data link path

Tags: windows-7

Currently I have been adding previous emails stored on my backup drive to the data file path and the majority of these files are working. However, with some of the .pst files I receive a pop up message saying:

> The file C:/Users/Documents/Outlook Files/Outlook(1).pst is not an Outlook data file (.pst).

It is my understanding that the file is in fact a .pst file / data Outlook file as stated in properties. How can I get Outlook 2010 to work?

Recently my computer crashed with all emails lost. Am I able to retrieve those emails even though that computer does not work? Is there some sort of server that stores all the emails that were sent and received with the email account?

Answer (score 2):

I would use Microsoft's ScanPST program to repair the data files that Outlook doesn't recognize. This program should be able recover as many email possible from the corrupted PSTs.

*ScanPST Instructions: [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287497) or [How-to-Geek](http://bit.ly/npwh4d)*

As for the server that stores all your emails, well, that is hard to answer. I'm assuming you are using Outlook because of work. If so, then the chances are, yes there is a server with all the email sent or received. However, chances are, your admin or IT policy will not allow you to recover them via the server. Usually, that server is only used to recover individuals' emails for legal or investigation reasons, or to do a full recover of everyone's emails on the server after a major IT disaster.